# Cannot connect to memcached

Tags: php, ubuntu, memcached

Im trying to connect to memcached on my local server in Ubuntu:

```
$memcached = new Memcached;
#
$memcached->addServer('localhost', 11211, 1) or die ("Could not connect");

var_dump($memcached);

var_dump($memcached->add('hello', 0, 400));
```

Why does var_dump show the following?

`object(Memcached)#1 (0) { } bool(false)`

Comment: What was the command you used to start memcached?

Comment: You're meant to start it? (Sorry I'm a complete looney, I thought it started when the apache server started). phpinfo says: `Additional .ini files parsed: memcached.ini`

Comment: It started before apache even. Without started memcached you couldn't connect. You can, so memcached seems to be started.

Comment: I opened up the terminal and typed in `memcached -v` and it seemed to work... weird..

Answer (score 0):

False return value means there was some error. See `$memcached->getResultMessage()` for additional details, it may help.

Comment: I see someone else has guessed `set`. Make sure you're below memcached's memory limit.

Answer (score 0):

I see *false* only on `add` operation - maybe this key already exists, try to use `set` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var_dump($memcached->add('hello', 0, false, 400));
```

The third param is a flag, to compress or not.

Answer (score -1):

check this if it can help
[How to install memcache in Ubuntu](http://ninjascripts.com/how-to-install-memcache-in-ubuntu-with-xampp/)